# How can I use np argmax on an array of lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data `y_hat` that looks like:

```
[[0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I want to get the `argmax` of each row so that I end up with a vector like:

```
[[3]
 [8]
 [8]
 ...
 [5]
 [1]
 [7]]
```

If I just do `np.argmax(y_hat)`, it returns a `1`.

Comment: Normally we describe `y_hat` as a 2d array, and you want to sum across 'rows',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way after `argmax` with `numpy` broadcast

```
a.argmax(axis = 1)[:,None]
```

Or

```
a[:,None].argmax(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.argmax` accepts an `axis` keyword argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax). Use that.

It's `axis=0` for columns, `axis=1` for rows.

Comment: He may also want to use the `keepdims` parameter.